# Jquery-Mootools conflict

Tags: jquery, mootools, conflict

i have been trying to make 2 scripts(1 mootol and 1 jquery) work at the same page to no avail..been researching many a forums and all but i still cant make the 2 work simultaneously.

this is how it looks in my header:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/wp-content/plugins/buddypress/bp-themes/bp-default/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
     jQuery.noConflict();
$(document).ready(function () { 
         var hide = false; 
     $("#posts-menu, .submenu").hover(function(){ 
         if (hide) clearTimeout(hide); 
         $(".submenu").fadeIn(); 
     }, function() { 
         hide = setTimeout(function() { 
             $(".submenu").fadeOut("slow"); 
         }, 250); 
     }); 

})(jQuery);
    </script>       
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/wp-content/plugins/buddypress/bp-themes/bp-default/js/mootools-core-1.3.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/wp-content/plugins/buddypress/bp-themes/bp-default/js/mootools-more-1.3.1.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/wp-content/plugins/buddypress/bp-themes/bp-default/js/wall.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/wp-content/plugins/buddypress/bp-themes/bp-default/js/wall-lide.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!-- 

window.addEvent('domready',function(){


    // -- horizontal
    var myHorizontalSlide = new Fx.Slide('login-welcome-div-slide', {mode: 'vertical'});


    $('slideout').addEvent('click', function(event){
        event.stop();
        myHorizontalSlide.slideOut();
    });


});

// -->  
</script>
```

i managed the mootools script to work even if theres a jquery.js call...
you can see that i already used `jQuery.noConflict();` in the 3rd line..

the problem is that the mootool scripts works if the jquery.noconflict is there but the jquery scripts doesnt work! now if remove the jquery.noconflict its now the other way around, the jquery script works but not the mootool scripts..i just couldnt make the 2 of them work!

any kind of help would be greatly appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not enclosing the jQuery code within an anonymous function. Try this:

```
(function($){
    // inside here $ will always mean jQuery
    $(document).ready(function () { 
         var hide = false; 
         $("#posts-menu, .submenu").hover(function(){ 
             if (hide) clearTimeout(hide); 
             $(".submenu").fadeIn(); 
         }, function() { 
             hide = setTimeout(function() { 
                 $(".submenu").fadeOut("slow"); 
             }, 250); 
         }); 
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: AMAZING! This one works! im so happy! pardon me..lol! thank you so much for this..^_^

Comment: @Dan: Glad I helped. Feel free to [accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) so this question gets marked as resolved.

Comment: oh ok! done! i pressed the up button earlier but it didnt work cause at least 15 reputation, thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

When you run in `noConflict` mode you can't use the `$` convenience method. You have to use the full form `jQuery` instead.

```
jQuery.noConflict();
// Do something with jQuery
jQuery("div p").hide();
// Do something with another library's $()
$("content").style.display = 'none';
```

Please avoid the use of 2 js libraries as it will increase your page load time which in turn has SEO implications (negative ones).

Comment: You're write, fingers moved faster than brain... however I never see the point of using 2 libraries...

Answer (score 1):

From a MooTools point of view.

You're including MooTools after jQuery. That's good. Because (if you don't use jQuery.noConflict), MooTools will see $ is already used by someone else and will leave it as it is.

You will have to replace the $ function with document.id() in your MooTools scripts.

jQuery has this noConflict mode. When using it, you will have to replace the $ function from jQuery with jQuery().

Either you replace the occurrences or you can use anonymous functions to keep the references to $ in your scripts and make it an alias for MooTools' document.id() or jQuery's jQuery().

```
(function($) {
    // $ will refer to MooTools' document.id() in this anonymous function
    // ...
})(document.id);

(function($) {
    // $ will refer to jQuery's jQuery() in this anonymous function
    // ...
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `jQuery` (case-sensitive) instead of `$` for the jQuery parts.

Answer (score 0):

You're clobbering the `$`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.noConflict();
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
  });
  // Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script>
```

Comment: i tried this..the jquery works but the mootools doesnt.. i cant post the code here, its too long

Answer (score 0):

You can try including the jQuery library before the MooTools library.

This [document](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries#Including_jQuery_before_Other_Libraries) should illustrate better